# 500: Internal Server Error Github and Vercel

Tags: github, next.js, vercel

I just deployed a website with Vercel using GitHub everything is fine but the main content that I have written in the file `index.js` is not showing and giving an error saying:

> 500: Internal Server Error

The Navbar, Header, and Footer are showing correctly because they're in other files. But the `index.js` is giving an error.

[Here is the website link](https://compositeschoollamahi.vercel.app)

You will see three images, the navbar, a banner of a school, the main content that gives an error, and a footer.

[Here is the link to the GitHub repo of the website](https://github.com/AgrimSingh421/compositeschoollamahi)

***Edit:***
When I checked the deployment status in Vercel, I saw every file in the folder `pages` except the file `index.js`. Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: Bring the folders,  files inside "src" folder to the root and delete the src folder. Should work.

Comment: @DanteDX, not working

Comment: can you push the latest changes to your repo ?